# Kafka single consumer to read from topic having multiple partitions from given offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka topic with 2 partitions, I want to create a consumer to read topic from a given offset, below is the sample code that I am using to read from given offset which is 9

```java
Properties configProperties = new Properties();
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test_consumer_group");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");

KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configProperties);
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

    }
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        for(TopicPartition topicPartition: partitions) {
            consumer.seek(topicPartition, 9);
        }
    }
});

try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println(record.topic() + ", " + record.partition() + ", " + record.offset() + ", " + record.value());
        }
    }
}catch(WakeupException ex){
    System.out.println("Exception caught " + ex.getMessage());
}finally{
    kafkaConsumer.close();
}
```

But i am seeing the following error

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher -  Fetch offset 9 is out of range for parition test-topic_partitions-0, resetting offset
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher -  Resetting offset for partition test-topic_partitions-0 to offset
```

I am using below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And also to mention the `delete.retention.ms` configured for this topic is 86400000 (which is 1 day) and `retention.ms` is configured as 172800000 (which is 2 days)

Can someone help how to resolve the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the partition does not have a record at offset 9. 
So either:

- you have currently less than 9 records in the partition
- records at least up to 9 have been deleted by the retention policy

You can use [`endOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-) and [`beginningOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-) to find the smallest and largest offsets in your partition. If you try to seek to an offset out of this range, the reset policy `auto.offset.reset` triggers to find a valid offset.